# Why prefer /WEB-INF/lib to /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF for webapps?

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, dependencies, manifest

I wonder why Java webapps specifications imposed a specific directory for dependencies: `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Indeed, why don't use classic `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file?

Someone will tell that webapps are so more secure because libs are physically integrated in WAR file.

But, if we think so, we could wonder :

Why for a simple Java application (simple JAR), there's no special directory for dependencies? It could be also more secure because no risk to have a wrong classpath (modified improperly for instance) in manifest file.

Other will tell that webapp is designed to be portable, so benefit of `/WEB-INF/lib` is to not worry about links dependencies.

I'm curious to know your opinions on the subject.

Comment: First this, are you aware that you can also just use `/META-INF/MANIFEST/MF` file in a WAR to specify dependencies instead of dropping them in `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: Yes, of course. That's why I doubt of the need of lib directory

Comment: You've already answered it: portability. Think about deploying a WAR to a 3rd party hosting where you have absolutely no access to other folders than the WAR deploy folder itself, or perhaps all you have is a webbased form with a single WAR file upload field. Where would you leave the dependencies?

Comment: Yes but we could say the same thing for a standalone Java Application, no ? For instance, a Jar put on different machines, and with a root directory for dependencies totally different. Shouldn't a standalone application be designed to be portable as webapps?

Comment: That's a different question. For that there exist lot of tools, even most IDEs have them builtin. Check the options when you want to export the project as a "Runnable JAR".

Comment: If you need the same behavior for standalone applications and want one single file check tools like Maven. They allow you to build a bundle with dependencies.

Comment: Also there is a solution to that: EAR (Enterprise Archive) which can contain several jars and wars and contains a complete application ready to be deployed to an enterprise application server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A jar is a standard library. For normal utility jars its probably better to keep them separate. If a library has a dependency on a different library and you need that dependent library more then once you would waste space, memory and maybe incorporte problems to due different library versions.

The web application however is an application bundle. You have to make sure that everythings works so you add the required libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Because the WEB-INF/lib makes for a very easy, self contained package of libraries and simplifies the entire deploy for the most common use cases.

```
/WEB-INF/web.xml
/WEB-INF/lib/utils.jar
/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/Servlet.class
/page.jsp
```

That's a full boat WAR right there, and with Servlet 3.0, the web.xml is basically empty. Simple layout, trivial to create, and a stand alone artifact to work with in the end.